# Set my own password when registering a multisite user or site

Tags: multisite, password

I'm wondering how I can change the network admin add "new user" or "new site" form so that I can set the password instead off having it randomly generated and e-mailed to the new user. There seems to be no real option or plugin for this oddly enough.

I've noticed that `user-new.php` is different for the main site vs inside /multisite but don't really know what to change.

I want to make it more like the add user form on a normal installation.

Answer (score 1):

What's worked for me in this situation is to use the Gravity Forms plugin with the User Registration Add on.  This allows me to create a form for my users to sign up for a sub-site, and allows them to set their user name and password.  The plugin also allows me to tie the signups into Mail Chimp, so i can add info automatically to my mail lists.  It also ties perfectly into PayPal.  The end result is a is a system where users can generate their own website on my network, subscribe to a mail list, and pay all in one take.  One example of it in action is at: http://worshiptimes.org/launch-your-website/

The developer option for Gravity Forms is a bit expensive, but with features like this, it is really worth it. 
Gravity Forms: http://www.gravityforms.com/
Gravity Forms User Reg Add on: http://www.gravityforms.com/add-ons/user-registration/

Hope this helps get you in the right direction.

Comment: thanks, i did ponder that idea but we are trying to custom code alot. maby ill report back here what we found.